# Create Tuples of rows from pandas dataframe with additional incremental value in tuple

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe df:

```
cc_code   name    age
345       alex    44
435       tom     43
567       dave    23
787       josh    24
```

I have to create List of tuples of rows from this dataframe such that i add a incremental value at the start element of every tuple.

```
start_id = 3
```

expected output:

```
[(3,345,alex,44),
(4,435,tom,43),
(5,567,dave,23),
(6,787,josh,24)]
```

Start_id should be added at the start of first row and then incremented for every row.

I wrote a simple statement to generate list of tuples:

```
df_tuple = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
```

But it is only forming list of tuples of rows. How do i incorporate the incremental start id at the start of every tuple in row list.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `enumerate` and add value to tuple:

```
start_id= 3
df_tuple = [(i, )+tuple(x) for i, x in enumerate(df.values, start_id)]
print (df_tuple)
[(3, 345, 'alex', 44), (4, 435, 'tom', 43), (5, 567, 'dave', 23), (6, 787, 'josh', 24)]
```

Comment: Working! :) Didn't knew about enumerate

Comment: Hey, i was using this, but faced another issue, Can you take a look at this question i posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53259404/weird-behaviour-of-enumerate-while-using-pandas-dataframe