# Weird Behaviour of Enumerate while using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe(df):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1],'l':[2],'m':[3],'k':[4],'s':[5],'f':[6]},index=[0])
```

I am using enumerate on row.

```
res = [tuple(x) for x in enumerate(df.values)]
print(res)
>>> [(1, 1, 6, 4, 2, 3, 5)]  ### the elements are int type
```

Now when i change the datatype of one column of my dataframe df:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1],'l':[2],'m':[3],'k':[4],'s':[5.5],'f':[6]},index=[0])
```

and again use enumerate, i get:

```
res2 = [tuple(x) for x in enumerate(df2.values)]
print(res2)
>>> [(1, 1.0, 6.0, 4.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.5)]  ### the elements data type has changed
```

I am not getting why?

Also i am looking for a solution where i have to get it in its own datatype.
For eg.

```
res = [(1, 1, 6, 4, 2, 3, 5.5)]
```

How can i Achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `enumerate`, that's a red herring. The issue is you are looking for mixed type output whereas Pandas prefers storing homogeneous data.

What you are looking for is **not** recommended with Pandas. Your data type should be `int` or `float`, not a combination. This has performance repercussions, since the only straightforward alternative is to use `object` dtype series, which only permits operations in Python time. Converting to `object` dtype is inefficient.

So here's what you *can* do:

```
res2 = df2.astype(object).values.tolist()[0]

print(res2)

[1, 6, 4, 2, 3, 5.5]
```

One method which avoids the `object` conversion:

```
from itertools import chain
from operator import itemgetter, methodcaller

iter_series = map(itemgetter(1), df2.items())
res2 = list(chain.from_iterable(map(methodcaller('tolist'), iter_series)))

[1, 6, 4, 2, 3, 5.5]
```

**Performance benchmarking**

If you want a *list of tuples* as output, one tuple for each row, then the series-based solution performs better:-

```
# Python 3.6.0, Pandas 0.19.2

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1],'l':[2],'m':[3],'k':[4],'s':[5.5],'f':[6]},index=[0])

from itertools import chain
from operator import itemgetter, methodcaller

n = 10**5
df2 = pd.concat([df2]*n)

def jpp_series(df2):
    iter_series = map(itemgetter(1), df2.items())
    return list(zip(*map(methodcaller('tolist'), iter_series)))

def jpp_object1(df2):
    return df2.astype(object).values.tolist()

def jpp_object2(df2):
    return list(map(tuple, df2.astype(object).values.tolist()))

assert jpp_series(df2) == jpp_object2(df2)

%timeit jpp_series(df2)   # 39.7 ms per loop
%timeit jpp_object1(df2)  # 43.7 ms per loop
%timeit jpp_object2(df2)  # 68.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: Looks like they want to do is put it in a tuple. Performance isn't really relevant here...

Comment: @coldspeed, That's entirely the point.. there's usually very little reason to "want to do" what OP wants to do.. `astype(object)` isn't efficient.

Comment: Indeed it isn't but I can think of cases where I'd prefer my integers to stay integers... In that case I see nothing wrong with suggesting this method.

Comment: @coldspeed, Possibly.. I've included a solution which doesn't need `object` dtype. You might be able to think of a cleverer way to do this :)

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that calling `df2.values` will cause `df2`'s data to be returned as a numpy array having a single dtype, where all the integers are also coerced to float.

You can prevent this coercion by operating on `object` arrays.

---

Use `astype(object)` to convert the underlying numpy array to object and prevent type coercion:

```
>>> [(i, *x) for i, x in df2.astype(object).iterrows()]
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.5, 6)]
```

Or,

```
>>> [(i, *x) for i, x in enumerate(df2.astype(object).values)]
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.5, 6)]
```

Or, on older versions,

```
>>> [(i,) + tuple(x) for i, x in enumerate(df2.astype(object).values)]
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.5, 6)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `df2` has mixed dtypes:

```
In [23]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1],'l':[2],'m':[3],'k':[4],'s':[5.5],'f':[6]},index=[0])
    ...:

In [24]: df2.dtypes
Out[24]:
a      int64
f      int64
k      int64
l      int64
m      int64
s    float64
dtype: object
```

therefore, using `.values` will "upcast" to the lowest common denominator. From [the doces](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html):

> The dtype will be a lower-common-denominator dtype (implicit
>   upcasting); that is to say if the dtypes (even of numeric types) are
>   mixed, the one that accommodates all will be chosen. Use this with
>   care if you are not dealing with the blocks.

It *looks* like you actually just want `.itertuples`:

```
In [25]: list(df2.itertuples())
Out[25]: [Pandas(Index=0, a=1, f=6, k=4, l=2, m=3, s=5.5)]
```

Note, this *conveniently* returns a list of `namedtuple` objects, if you really just want plain tuples, map `tuple` on to it:

```
In [26]: list(map(tuple, df2.itertuples()))
Out[26]: [(0, 1, 6, 4, 2, 3, 5.5)]
```

But there's really no need.